# Passing REST API Authentication Token Working in PostMan But Not Python Requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python Requests to access some information via a REST API. The API that I am using requires authentication, and after a login request the response will contain a session ID that is then supposed to be included in the header of all future requests. The API documentation states:

> Once the authentication is successful, a JSON response with an access token is returned. The
> token needs to be set in the headers of all
> subsequent requests for them to be processed successfully. The API client should add an HTTP
> header with name "blabla_session_id", the same cookie name as in the Web Application

I am able to successfully send a login request and receive a response with the session ID, however I am having trouble using Python Requests to add the session ID to the header. I am using the following code:

```
# Functions

def login(base_url, username, password):
    print("Getting token...")
    header = {'content-type':'application/json'}

    data_get = {'email': username,
                'password':password,
                'workspaceId':12345678} 

    r = requests.post(base_url+'login', headers=header, json=data_get)

    if r.ok:
        print("Login Success!")
        global session_id   
        session_id = r.cookies['blabla_session_id']
        print("Session ID is %s" %session_id)

    else:
        print("Login Fail...")
        print("HTTP %i - %s, Message %s" % (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))

def logout():
    header = {'blabla_session_id':session_id,'content-type':'application/json'}
    print (header)

    r = requests.put(base_url+'logout', headers=header)
    print (r.request.headers)

    if r.ok:
        print("Logout Success")
    else:
        print("Logout Failed")
        print("HTTP %i - %s, Message %s" % (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))

def main():
    login(base_url, api_login, api_password)
    logout()

# Main Program
main()
```

When I execute this, I get the following response:

```
Getting token...
Login Success!
Session ID is LABS-FReGnWuzzj7oYQ4nzPdvB55rOpctU48s%7C
{'blabla_session_id': 'LABS-FReGnWuzzj7oYQ4nzPdvB55rOpctU48s%7C', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'blabla_session_id': 'LABS-FReGnWuzzj7oYQ4nzPdvB55rOpctU48s%7C', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '0'}
Logout Failed
HTTP 401 - , Message {"status":401,"errors":[{"code":401,"message":"There is no access token associated with this request or the access token is not valid."}]}
```

[Command Line Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBk4Q.png)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? As the title suggests, I did try using PostMan to verify the API and I am able to login, add the session ID to the header and logout without issue. I suspect this has something to do with the format of the header, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Surprised you aren’t using a requests session; by using a single session for the login ans subsequent requests you won’t have to mess about copying cookies.

Comment: Thanks! I did see this feature in the requests documentation and agree, it would definitely save me having to add the session ID to the header for every request, but I was hoping to successfully pass in the session ID at least once using the present method before changing the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to using a single requests `session` and that will propagate particularly cookies across all your http actions ensuring that successful authentication is carried over into all requests.

For example:

```
import requests

def login(s,base_url, username, password):
    print("Getting token...")
    header = {'content-type':'application/json'}

    data_get = {'email': username,
                'password':password,
                'workspaceId':12345678} 

    r = s.post(base_url+'login', headers=header, json=data_get)

    if r.ok:
        print("Login Success!")
        global session_id   
        session_id = r.cookies['blabla_session_id']
        print("Session ID is %s" %session_id)

    else:
        print("Login Fail...")
        print("HTTP %i - %s, Message %s" % (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))

def logout(s):
    header = {'blabla_session_id':session_id,'content-type':'application/json'}
    print (header)

    r = s.put(base_url+'logout', headers=header)
    print (r.request.headers)

    if r.ok:
        print("Logout Success")
    else:
        print("Logout Failed")
        print("HTTP %i - %s, Message %s" % (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))

def main():
    s = requests.session()
    login(s,base_url, api_login, api_password)
    logout(s)

# Main Program
main()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this fails in the same way as not using a session.

Comment: I got it! Using a session to manage the cookies does work, as long as I don't add the Session ID to the header at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly. Hopefully you can accept and upvote my answer if I answered your question.